# PowerShell : remove XML node

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to remove node "A"

```
$xml=@"
<migrationManifests>
  <file>A</file>
  <file>B</file>
  <file>C</file>
  <file>D</file>
  <file>E</file>
  <file>F</file>
</migrationManifests>
"@

$data = -join("/migrationManifests[@file='A']")

$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode($data) 
$null = $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
    
$xml.migrationManifests.file
```

And I get this error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there - but `@` selects an attribute, not a node:

try changing

```
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode($data)
```

to

```
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//migrationManifests/file[.="A"]')
```

Comment: Worth pointing out, OP is missing the cast to `[xml]` to convert the string to an `xml` object: `$xml = [xml]@'.....'@`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon You're absolutely right; forgot to mention that.